# Dashcode: How to add custom inspector panel for custom Dashcode Parts?

Tags: dashcode

I like using Dashcode for making quick little web apps, but it specifically targets the iphone version of mobile safari, which is not acceptable for cross-platform development.  I've developed a number of laundry-list hacks that I tend semi-manually add to my scripts to facilitate cross platform development (like, say, to the Android or Palm) and to perform useful iPhone tricks, like stopping the 'bounce' associated with web apps on the iphone and I'm turning these into custom Dashcode Parts so that I can drag & drop them into my project. This is mostly working so far, but here my dilemma:

How can I create a custom Inspector component to go along with my custom Dashcode Part?  Is it possible?  Ever heard of being done?  What are the minimum steps?

I see some compiled .nib files, and an existin Dashcode Part's Info.plist has a key `CYPartInspectorClass` that maps to `CYPushButtonInspectorPane` and  like `CYPushButtonInspectorPane` and that apparently corresponds to `English.lproj/CYPushButtonInspectorPane.nib` which is a compile .nib.   Does this imply that everything here is semi-hardcoded, and thus impossible to add my Inspector changes?

Any pointers to the above would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I don't *think* this is possible, but I'd still be happy to eventually be proven wrong.